# How is it declared the transaction manager in this Spring example project? How it works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

I am studying for Spring Core certification and I am finding some doubts related to how Spring handle transaction.

So I have an exercise in which I find something like this.

In a class named **rewards.internal.RewardNetworkImpl** I have this method:

```
@Transactional
public RewardConfirmation rewardAccountFor(Dining dining) {
    Account account = accountRepository.findByCreditCard(dining.getCreditCardNumber());
    Restaurant restaurant = restaurantRepository.findByMerchantNumber(dining.getMerchantNumber());
    MonetaryAmount amount = restaurant.calculateBenefitFor(account, dining);
    AccountContribution contribution = account.makeContribution(amount);
    accountRepository.updateBeneficiaries(account);
    return rewardRepository.confirmReward(contribution, dining);
}
```

So this method perform some operation on some services classes (that substantially execute some queries on the DB). I want that all these operations are executed into a single transaction (that guaranteed the ACID properties) so I annotate this method with the **@Transactional** annotation. Ok, I think that this is pretty clear for me.

My Spring project is splitted into 2 main folder (2 directory I think) that contains the same packages). These folder are named respectively **src/test/java** and **src/main/java**. The first one contains the classes related to the **JUnit test** and the second one contains classes related to the proper project that implements the application), this is a screenshot of how is organized my project:

[image]

Ok, now in the exercise it say tha I have to define a bean named **transactionManager** that configures a **DataSourceTransactionManager** adding this method to the Spring configuration class named **rewards.SystemTestConfig** that is situated into the **src/test/java** folder:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

So it is pretty clear for me that this method configure a bean named **transactionManager** implemented by a **DataSourceTransactionManager** that use a **DataSource** object.

My doubt is related to the place where this configuration is putted. Infact it is putted inside the **rewards.SystemTestConfig** inside the **src/test/java** folder (the folder that contains the **JUnit stuff**.

So my doubts are: is this configuration related only for the test environment or is it global to my entire project? (the **transactionManager** works only for the test environment or is it used also into my concrete application?)

I have another configuration class into the **src/main/java** folder, this one:

```
package config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import rewards.RewardNetwork;
import rewards.internal.RewardNetworkImpl;
import rewards.internal.account.AccountRepository;
import rewards.internal.account.JdbcAccountRepository;
import rewards.internal.restaurant.JdbcRestaurantRepository;
import rewards.internal.restaurant.RestaurantRepository;
import rewards.internal.reward.JdbcRewardRepository;
import rewards.internal.reward.RewardRepository;


//  TODO-03: Add an annotation to instruct the container to look for the 
//  @Transactional annotation.  Save all work, run RewardNetworkTests.  It should pass.  

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RewardsConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public RewardNetwork rewardNetwork(){
        return new RewardNetworkImpl(
            accountRepository(), 
            restaurantRepository(), 
            rewardRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountRepository accountRepository(){
        JdbcAccountRepository repository = new JdbcAccountRepository();
        repository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository(){
        JdbcRestaurantRepository repository = new JdbcRestaurantRepository();
        repository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public RewardRepository rewardRepository(){
        JdbcRewardRepository repository = new JdbcRewardRepository();
        repository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return repository;
    }

}
```

As you can see it don't contains an explicit configuration of the **transactionManager** bean but it is annoted with **@EnableTransactionManagement** annotation. I know that this annotation defines a Bean Post-Processor that proxies @Transactional beans and so happen:

- Target object wrapped in a proxy (using an an Around advice)
- Proxy implements the following behavior: **Transaction started before entering the method** AND **Commit at the end of the method** AND **Rollback if method throws a RuntimeException**.

But I can't understand why in the **rewards.SystemTestConfig** configuration class of the test environment it is explicitly declared the **transactionManager** bean and in the **RewardsConfig** class (the class that configure the proper application) it is not declared the **transactionManager** (I think that this bean is absolutly needed to operate with transaction) but in its place there is the **@EnableTransactionManagement** annotation.

So my doubts are:

1) Declaring the **transactionManager** bean into **rewards.SystemTestConfig** configuration class of the test environment it is global and it work also for the proper application folder (but I don't think).

2) Noting with **@EnableTransactionManagement** annotation the **rewards.SystemTestConfig** (that configure the proper application) it is automatically created a transaction manager. But what kind? and especially how do you know which datasource should use?

Can you help me to understand how it work? What am I missing?

Comment: where did you pulled out this project from? Is it shared somewhere online, so that everyone can have a look? e.g. on github?

Comment: BTW, if you want to better understand instantiation of Spring beans, turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.* package.

Comment: Do you have rewards.SystemTestConfig also in src/main? Because you say '... the rewards.SystemTestConfig (that configure the proper application)...'

Comment: If your main program uses the rewards.SystemTestConfig from src/test then it also uses the transactionManager bean from it. Please take into account that when you start a program from eclipse the program access classes/resources from both src/main and src/test. Second, in eclipse are typically the classes/resources from src/test before those from src/main. That means that if you have some identically named configs (XML or class) in both src/main and src/test, in eclipse those from src/test wins over those in src/main (for given full qualified name, i.e. package + class/resource name).

Comment: As the others already mentioned, configuring log4j to DEBUG results in output, where you might be able to see how (based on which xml or class) spring creates transaction manager bean.